# how to get only folder name when extract the zip file in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, zip

I am using zip library to zip a folder or directory

My path structure is

```
   $estructure = "/home/administrator/Downloads/pdf_files/"
```

And iam zipping folder using below code

```
   $this->zip->read_dir($estructure);
   $this->zip->archive('/var/www/');
   $this->zip->download('folder_name.zip');
```

Now problem is when I extract compressed directory it gives full path like

```
  /home/administrator/Downloads/pdf_files/
```

what I need is when I extract the zip file its should only diretcory like pdf_file,

Could any help me on that please? thanks

Comment: What code are you using to extract the file?

Comment: I am not using code to extract, using Archive mounter software.

Answer (score 1):

---

Ok I got answer

```
  $this->zip->read_dir($estructure,FALSE);
  ob_end_clean();
```

Its working fine now.